# Android GridView displaying incorrect item and fragment displaying on top of another fragment

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I am implementing ActionBar Tab to display 3 tabs, each of which contains a GridLayout.  The problem arises when the view is scrolled down, the hidden items appear but the order is somehow scrambled.  The screen shows only 4 items initially (in a 2 column grid), but when the 5th comes into view, item 1 is shown instead, but the 6th is  correct.  The 7th and 8th items are also incorrect, and the error is similarly displayed on the other tabs.  Scrolling across the tabs also jumbles up the order.

[image: Jumbled Gridview order]

The second problem arises when I implement onItemClickListener on each item in the grid, which is supposed to replace the fragment with one showing larger view.  Instead of replacing the view, it sits on top of the display with the bottom fragment showing through.

[image: Fragment overlayed]

I can't figure out what's wrong.  Here's my code

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
public static String[] mTabItems;
public static int[] mTabImages;
public static GridView mGridview;
public static String[][] itemName = new String[3][8];
public static int [][] itemPics = new int[3][8];

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (int tab = 1; tab<4; tab++){
        for (int item = 1; item<9; item++){
            String image = "tab" + tab + "_" + item;
            int imageIden = getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable","com.tabgriddrawer");
            itemPics[tab-1][item-1] = imageIden;
            itemName[tab-1][item-1] = image;
            i++;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {            
        Fragment frag = new SectionFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(SectionFragment.ARG_TAB_NUMBER, i);
        frag.setArguments(arguments);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;//set 3 tabs
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Tab " + (position + 1);
    }
}

public static class SectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_TAB_NUMBER = "tab_number";
    public static Bundle detailArguments;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Bundle arg = getArguments();
        int tab = arg.getInt(ARG_TAB_NUMBER);
        mTabItems = new String[8];
        mTabImages = new int[8];

        for (int m=0; m<8; m++){
            mTabItems[m] = itemName[tab][m];
            mTabImages[m] = itemPics[tab][m];
        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_gridview, container, false);
        CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mTabItems,mTabImages);
        mGridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_grid_view);
        mGridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mGridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id){
                int t = arg.getInt(ARG_TAB_NUMBER);
                Fragment itemDetailFragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
                detailArguments = new Bundle();
                detailArguments.putString("ItemName", itemName[t][position]);
                detailArguments.putInt("ImageId", itemPics[t][position]);
                itemDetailFragment.setArguments(detailArguments);

                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                Fragment itemFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.hide(itemFragment);
                ft.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, itemDetailFragment, "detail");
                ft.commit();

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Custom Gridview adapter:

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private final String[] libraryItem;
private final int[] imageId;

public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] libItem,int[] Imageid ) {
      mContext = c;
      this.imageId = Imageid;
      this.libraryItem = libItem;
  }
@Override
public int getCount() {
  return libraryItem.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
  return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
  return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View grid;

  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gridview_item, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageItem);
        textView.setText(libraryItem[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
      } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
      }
  return grid;
}
```

}

Item Detail Fragment:

```
public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private Context mContext;
private String mItemDesc;
private int mImageId;
private String mItemName;
static int tab;
static int position;

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){  
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemimage);
        image.setImageResource(mImageId);
        TextView itemtext = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        itemtext.setText(mItemName);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

        mImageId = (int)MainActivity.SectionFragment.detailArguments.getInt("ImageId");
        mItemName = (String)MainActivity.SectionFragment.detailArguments.get("ItemName");
        }

    public void onBackPressed(){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_frame, new MainActivity.SectionFragment());
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
        }
}
```

Main XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- moved viewpager to inside drawer layout -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Gridview XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >

</GridView>
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't look at your whole code. . . only the getView method in your Adapter, cause that is where I suspect the problem is.

When the convertView is not null, you are simply returning convertView. . . this is what is causing the problem. When you do this, you are returning a view that the adapter is attempting to recycle from one gridview position to another. That's why the image from one view is appearing in another. Instead, do this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View grid;

  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gridview_item, null);
      } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
      }

        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageItem);
        textView.setText(libraryItem[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
  return grid;
}
```